# Docker - python app not available by REST

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

We have simple app on python: REST-controller, returning JSON.

It's here:
https://github.com/NikaGolybeva/smt

Controller:

```
#!flask/bin/python
from flask import Flask, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

tasks = [
    {
        'id': 1,
        'title': u'Buy groceries',
        'description': u'Milk, Cheese, Pizza, Fruit, Tylenol',
        'done': False
    },
    {
        'id': 2,
        'title': u'Learn Python',
        'description': u'Need to find a good Python tutorial on the web',
        'done': False
    }
]

from flask import abort


@app.route('/test', methods=['GET'])
def get_tasks():
    return jsonify({'tasks': tasks})

@app.route('/test/<int:task_id>', methods=['GET'])
def get_task(task_id):
    task = list(filter(lambda t: t['id'] == task_id, tasks))
    if len(task) == 0:
        abort(404)
    return jsonify({'task': task[0]})



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7
EXPOSE 5000
ADD run.py /
RUN pip install pystrich
RUN pip install flask
CMD [ "python", "./run.py" ]
```

We run app with docker on port 5000:

```
v-chernyshov@v-chernyshov:~/IdeaProjects/smt$ docker build -t smt .

...

v-chernyshov@v-chernyshov:~/IdeaProjects/smt$ docker run -p 5000:5000 smt
 * Serving Flask app "run" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 309-988-075
```

Awaiting, that when we try to send request on `http://localhost:5000/test/1`, app shall return JSON. But by the fact, app is unreacheable.

Okay. Variant 2.

Adding app into docker-compose.yml and deploy on virtual server. docker-compose looks like here:

```
services:
  web:
    image: account/front:0.0.1
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - 80:3000
  back:
    image: account/back:0.0.3
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - 8099:8099
  smth:
    image: nikagolybeva/smth:0.0.1
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
```

We have back on java & smth on python. I wrote method, which trying to send request to smtn by REST once a minute:

```
@Scheduled(initialDelay = 1000L, fixedDelay = 60000L)
public void testPython() {
    String url = "http://smth:5000/test/1";
    log.info("testing python, url: {}", url);
    PythonTestDto pythonTestDto = restTemplate.getForObject(url, PythonTestDto.class);
    String result = "";
    try {
        result = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(pythonTestDto);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }
    log.info("response: {}", result);
}
```

Run it with docker-compose.

back & message deploys on their ports:

```
smth_1_f8c6211ef46d |  * Serving Flask app "run" (lazy loading)
smth_1_f8c6211ef46d |  * Environment: production
smth_1_f8c6211ef46d |    WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
smth_1_f8c6211ef46d |    Use a production WSGI server instead.
smth_1_f8c6211ef46d |  * Debug mode: on
smth_1_f8c6211ef46d |  * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
smth_1_f8c6211ef46d |  * Restarting with stat
smth_1_f8c6211ef46d |  * Debugger is active!
smth_1_f8c6211ef46d |  * Debugger PIN: 769-002-661

...

back_1_9622a732ea20 | 2019-09-26 08:16:31.725  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8099 (http) with context path ''
```

Ping smth from back:

```
root@kvm1:/home/xpendence/docker# docker-compose exec back ping smth
PING smth (172.21.0.3): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.21.0.3: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.396 ms
64 bytes from 172.21.0.3: seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.142 ms
64 bytes from 172.21.0.3: seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.175 ms
64 bytes from 172.21.0.3: seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.195 ms
64 bytes from 172.21.0.3: seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.113 ms
64 bytes from 172.21.0.3: seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.127 ms
64 bytes from 172.21.0.3: seq=6 ttl=64 time=0.521 ms
^C
--- smth ping statistics ---
7 packets transmitted, 7 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.113/0.238/0.521 ms
```

It's okay, but trying to send request by REST fails:

```
back_1_9622a732ea20 | org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://smth:5000/test/1": Connection refused (Connection refused); nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

Please, tell me, what's wrong

Comment: Can you try adding `app.run(host='0.0.0.0')` in your `run.py` to listen to any IP ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site is running on docker (like a vm it has its own IP) so you cant access it writing localhost from your local machine.
With docker-machine, you can get the IP of the VM from the docker-machine IP output, and then connect to the IP you got.

Btw, you have to set your flask application to listen on 0.0.0.0 if I'm not mistaken for it to work.

Check this link for some reference ...
https://medium.com/@mtngt/docker-flask-a-simple-tutorial-bbcb2f4110b5

Comment: Only if you are using docker-machine. If you are on linux and use native docker engine, then those containers should be accessible on localhost. More about docker machine: https://docs.docker.com/machine/overview/

Comment: Thanks for the correction, if so I think changing the IP of the flask app to 0.0.0.0 will fix the problem (: